# paypal api for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, paypal

I am recently developing a business application naming MyTicket.
I want that paypal gateway should be open within the app So
for that is there any paypal api in blackberry that helps me in fulfilling this 
task.
I have already tried with creating a Paypal API wrapper for example using PHP, which is used by a proxy page. Then in the BlackBerry, use standard HTTP requests to send GET/POST requests to the proxy page.
 The proxy page will in turn use the wrapper you created to set up payment for you and your customer.But by following this way we are able to make credit card payments with the application and entire transaction will happen at the server end and in response we may obtain a result at client end that transaction is happened successfully.
But i want that the paypal transaction will happen with the paypal account.So is there any 
sdk in blackberry which helps me in fulfilling this request.

Thanks And Regards
Pinkesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

There was an API, but they dropped support. I think now the only platforms supported are iOS and Android: [PayPal -Mobile Payment Libraries](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries)

*(If you want to check out how the BB version was like, or if you manage to find the jar, this was the development guide:[MPL Guide for BlackBerry](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Blackberry.pdf))*

Now RIM has a Payment Service that might help you: [Payment Service](https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/payment.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard Express Checkout API within your app it'll automatically utilize the mobile checkout experience.

I use this in my jQuery Mobile Apps and it works great.  If you're building a native Java app, though, you might have to use some sort of an embedded web page to make it work.